# Is a dynamic website with lots of urls possible with wordpress

Tags: themes

I have a  website which is built in CodeIgniter and bootstrap, This is very dynamic website with many URLs, Similar to this https://aktien.guide/

Is it possible to build such a website in WordPress, If yes, Do I need to create a new theme from scratch, Or I can do this with any theme

Comment: What do you mean "many URLs"? Why would any website not be able to have 'many URLs'?

Comment: @JacobPeattie  I mean, If someone enters `http://website/url1`  in the URL.  in the core PHP i can handle that and find the result in the database according to the url1. I don't need to create each page manually, How to do this in WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress URL handling is data-centric. That is a certain URL is matched to a rewrite rule, and is turned into query variables, which explain to WP which data to query in database and present.

If you are considering migrating another site to WordPress you would have two typical options:

1. Migrate the data to native WP data types, such as custom post types and taxonomies. In this case you get URLs working "for free".
2. Integrate alternate data structures/source into WP site. In this case you preserve data as is, but you would need to spend significant effort to implement custom rewrite rules and how should WP *retrieve* the data from custom sources.

Comment: Thanks,  I think i can't migrate my data to native WP data types. So i will use my previous database, I have decided to create plugin to access that data from mysql by wpdb class, And will use shortcode to display that data on the pages, But i need to create around 400 pages. that is annoying

Comment: You don't _have_ to create pages, but you will need to create custom rewrite rules otherwise / virtual pages, which is a little more advanced technique.

Comment: Yeah, they are too advance for me, I tried to understand virtual pages plugin, But there is no clear information available, Can you provide any good reference for the virtual pages/rewrite rules

Comment: Not on top of my head, sorry. If you search around "virtual pages" and "endpoints" should be the right keywords for it in WP context.

Comment: no problem, I will find that, Thanks for your quick responses, It was a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress and codeigniter are two different things. What is need of wordpress if codeigniter is there and vice versa. These both are frameworks. This is not a good at all approach to have the wordpress and codeigniter on same platform.

Another thing the site you are referring is based on ruby on rails.

And yes you can have as many as you can URLS in the Wordpress.

Comment: @fuxia Do i need to create each page manually in wordpress

Comment: what are you using first confirm that wordpress or codeigniter. If wordpress you can add pages or you can add your templates manually in the the themese files.

Comment: @user129828 No, you don't. :) Search for "virtual pages", "endpoints" and similar terms on our site, we have lots of interesting solutions for that.

Comment: Sorry i edited my question, i am trying to use WordPress instead of CodeIgniter, If i create a new template, Will that work for all urls

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org Go nuts

Comment: @fuxia Hey, i play chess too https://www.chess.com/member/php-webdeveloper